# x360ce emulator error message: Error calling SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW: 122

Tags: ancestors-the-humankind-odyssey, x360ce

I downloaded the latest version of *x360ce*. But when I try to run I'm facing with this error message:

[image: Error calling SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW: 122.]

This doesn't happen with the older versions (but these old versions didn't work with the Ancestors game). I have also installed the latest .NET Framework. How can I get this to work? Or are there any other alternatives? This is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

An older version of the x360 emulator would do it. Search for x360 v 4.10 and the System.Exception: Error calling SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW: 122 will be solved

Answer (score -2):

An older version of x360ce, version 4.10.0.0 solved the issue for me:

Comment: Video/link only answers are highly discouraged, so please summarize the essential details into your answer. Otherwise, if the video were to ever be taken down, the answer would become obsolete